# Navigation bar overlapping image after back segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

[image]

Navigation bar overlaps the image after user back from segue.

When the view first loaded it looks ok but after performing the segue and come back it looks like this.

here is the code for that image

```
let logoContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 67))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -30, width: 200, height: 67))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "navbarlogo")
        imageView.image = image
        logoContainer.addSubview(imageView)
        navigationItem.titleView = logoContainer
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the imageView.clipsToBounds = false and same thing for the logo container?

Comment: @jake.lange yeah didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your problem is the fact you are creating an overlap of the ImageView by specifying a -30 y coordinate.  It's higher in the z-order (compared to your navigation bar) in one case but lower in the z-order in the segue scenario.

I suspect if you use "Debug View Hierarchy" in XCode in both scenarios, you would be able to see this is what is happening.

I would change your approach as to how the logo container is being laid out